# factorial of a number in pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, syntax-error

The following pl/sql program generates an error on execution on line the sum :=temp*sum; encountered symbol ; when expecting ( . Please explain my mistake.

```
declare
  n number;
  temp number;
  sum number := 1;
begin
  n := &n;
  temp := n;
  while temp>0 loop
    sum := temp*sum;
    temp := temp-1;
  end loop;
  dbms_output.put_line('Factorial of '||n||' is '||sum);
end;
/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sum is reserved word in sql. Change variable name like

```
declare
  n number;
  temp number;
  sum_ number := 1;
begin
  n := &n;
  temp := n;
  while temp>0 loop
    sum_ := temp*sum_;
    temp := temp-1;
  end loop;
  dbms_output.put_line('Factorial of '||n||' is '||sum_);
end;
/
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was struggling with it for quite long.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe not the answer to your question, but there is no need for PL/SQL here:

```
select round(exp(sum(ln(level))))
from dual
connect by level <= 5;
```

where 5 is your number (`5!`).

Additionally, if you like to operate faster in PL/SQL use `pls_integer` instead of `number`.

**UPDATE**

So according to comments I felt free to test:

```
create or replace package test_ is

  function by_query(num number) return number deterministic;

  function by_plsql(num number) return number deterministic;

end test_;

/

create or replace package body test_ is

  function by_query(num number) return number deterministic
    is
      res    number;
  begin
    select round(exp(sum(ln(level))))
    into res
    from dual
    connect by level <= num;

    return res;
  end;

  function by_plsql(num number) return number deterministic
    is
      n number := 0;
  begin
    for i in 1..num loop
      n := n + ln(i);
    end loop;

    return round(exp(n));
  end;

end test_;
```

So there are two functions with different content. Test query:

```
declare
  dummy   number;
begin
  for i in 1..10000 loop
    dummy := test_.by_query(5);
  end loop;
end;
```

0.094 sec.

```
declare
  dummy   number;
begin
  for i in 1..10000 loop
    dummy := test_.by_plsql(5);
  end loop;
end;
```

0.094 sec.

You'll say I am cheater and using `deterministic` keyword but here it is obvious and is needed by logic. If I remove it, the same scripts are working 1.7 sec vs 1.3 sec, so procedure is only a bit faster, there is no even double-win in performance. The totally opposite effect you will get if you use the function in a query so it is a fair trade.

Comment: Running sql to compute something that could be computed in pure PL/SQL is, I strongly suspect, much less efficient. The rule-of-thumb "don't use PL/SQL if SQL can be used" does *not* apply here.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp, I would not be that sure, please prove your guess and only after that I will understand "-1".

Comment: `declare n number := 0; begin for i in 1..5 loop n := n + ln(i); end loop; dbms_output.put_line(round(exp(n))); end;`

Comment: Feel free to test that on your own system, but I find my function can execute at least 10,000x faster, primarily because it doesn't involve any SQL parsing or execution.

Comment: Yours was still a smart answer, though, to use the logarithm function - kudos :)

Comment: @JeffreyKemp, I felt free :) check the updated answer

Comment: Try running your plsql version 10,000,000 times. Then the sql version. No deterministic so that it does actually execute each time.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp, I will not remove `deterministic`: it is very and very stupid to do that. Oracle will restrict you in the length of meaningful `number` on 18s iteration and it is stupid to disable the cache for the function which has only 18 meaningful outputs. Maybe in other function your clue is right, but here it is not: this is a concrete situation, and I proved that it can be as fast as PL/SQL block. You can agree or disagree: it is your choice, but this solution works, and works very fast. I do not care about anything else.

Comment: Most of your 0.094s is just overhead - you have proven nothing about the relative performance. To find the faster method, you *must* eliminate other sources of variation - you tried to do this by running it 10,000 times, but then you added the deterministic keyword to enable caching. The whole idea of caching is to *stop* the program running multiple times for the same input!

Comment: It doesn't matter if I "agree or disagree", what matters is proof. I've proven PL/SQL is faster *in this instance*, you have proven nothing.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare
    n number;
    i number;
    sum_of_log_10s number;
    exponent number;
    base number;

begin
    n := &n;

    i := 1;
    sum_of_log_10s := 0;

    while i <= n loop
        -- do stuff
        sum_of_log_10s := sum_of_log_10s + log(10,i);
        i := i + 1;
    end loop;

    dbms_output.put_line('sum of logs = '||sum_of_log_10s);

    exponent := floor(sum_of_log_10s);

    base := power(10,sum_of_log_10s - exponent);

    dbms_output.put_line(n||'! = '||base||' x 10^'||exponent);

end;
```

Comment: Some explanation in addition to just code will make this answer more useful to future readers.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this code that I like even better than @smnbbrv's answer.  It's a great way to check the speed of a machine.  I've been using a variation of this since my Atari 800

```
ALTER SESSION FORCE PARALLEL DDL PARALLEL 16; 
ALTER SESSION FORCE PARALLEL DML PARALLEL 16; 
ALTER SESSION FORCE PARALLEL QUERY PARALLEL 16; 

with t as (
    select /*+materialize*/
        rownum i 
    from dual connect by rownum < 100000 -- put number to calculate n! here
)
,t1 as (
    select /*+parallel(t,16)*/ /*+materialize*/
        sum(log(10,i)) logsum
    from t
    )
select 
    trunc(power(10,(mod(logsum,1))),3) ||' x 10^'||trim(to_char(floor(logsum),'999,999,999,999')) factorial
--  logsum
from t1
;
```

-- returns 2.824 x 10^456,568

Comment: this is unreadable. use code formatting which is explained by clicking help.  Also, provide context for your answer by explaining that you are elaborating on @smnbbrv's answer. Your answer has nothing to do with the question and it isn't clear what you like "even better" than

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple code for finding factorial of number at run time...

```
declare
 -- it gives the final answer after computation 
        fac number :=1; 
        -- given number n 
        -- taking input from user 
        n number := &1; 

        -- start block 
        begin   

        -- start while loop  
        while n > 0 loop 

        -- multiple with n and decrease n's value 
        fac:=n*fac;    

        --dbms_output.put(n||'*'); 
        n:=n-1;    
        end loop;    
        -- end loop 

        -- print result of fac 
        dbms_output.put_line(fac); 

        -- end the begin block 
        end;
```